# Why does React log to Chrome-Console "Content-script injection failed" (from allpages.js) when I never set up code to inject a script?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom, console.log

I am nearly done with my code for my new Website but am really bothered that the following gets somehow logged to my Chrome-Console:

[image]

For instance, it gets printed when I switch between pages of my Website (using react-router-dom). I am not consciously injecting any script (nor do I know how that would work or why I would do such a thing).
I don't even know what "allpages.js" is, I never came across it so far.
If I click on it, to see the area that throws the error, I get the following (it is on line 83):

[image]

Happy to provide any further info or code and thanks everyone!

Comment: Is this possibly a script your app is loading? Is this some browser extension? Looking at the `chrome` object references leads me to believe this code is all external to your React app and it something in your browser. Do you see these console logs when navigating *other* website's pages?

Comment: This is indeed the explanation -> it did not occur to me before, but I am using this "lumaly"-extension which is named above, it seems that it just fails within the context of my localhost-page. I inspected my page in Safari and there is nothing being logged there. So all good. Thanks for the help, it saved me hours of frustration :)